# PostgreSQL query: getting latest forecast before a deadline, compare to actual

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to lookup the historical actual and forecasted wind, broken down by hour and day.

I have multiple forecasts for a certain hour of the day. And I have a trade deadline of 10am EST for the next day's trades, so I want the most recent forecast before then on the same line as the actual wind for that hour.

Complicating matters is that the timestamps are in GMT, which is 5 hours ahead of EST.

```
   WITH
   forecast_prep AS (
       SELECT
             date_trunc('day', (foretime - interval '5 hours')) :: DATE AS Foredate,
             extract(HOUR FROM (foretime - interval '5 hours')) + 1     AS foreHE,
             lat,
             lon,
             max(windspeed) as forecast,
             max(as_of) - interval '5 hours'      AS as_of
       FROM weather.forecast
       WHERE date_trunc('day', foretime) :: DATE - as_of >= INTERVAL '9 hours'
       GROUP BY Foredate, foreHE, lat, lon
  ),
  tmp AS (
     SELECT
       meso.station,
       meso.lat,
       meso.lon,
       (meso.timestmp - interval '5 hours') as timestmp,
       date_trunc('day', (meso.timestmp - interval '5 hours')) :: DATE  AS Date,
       extract(HOUR FROM (meso.timestmp - interval '5 hours')) + 1      AS HE,
       CAST(AVG(meso.windspd) AS NUMERIC(19, 2)) AS Actual
     FROM weather.meso
     GROUP BY station, lat, lon, timestmp, Date, HE
  )
SELECT 
   tmp.station, tmp.Date, tmp.HE, tmp.Actual, forecast_prep.forecast, forecast_prep.as_of
FROM tmp
INNER JOIN forecast_prep ON (
   tmp.lat = forecast_prep.lat 
   AND tmp.lon = forecast_prep.lon 
   AND tmp.Date = forecast_prep.Foredate
   AND tmp.HE = forecast_prep.foreHE
)
WHERE 
   (tmp.timestmp BETWEEN '2016-02-01' AND '2016-02-02') 
   AND (tmp.station = 'KSBN')
GROUP BY 
   tmp.station, tmp.Date, tmp.HE, forecast_prep.forecast, forecast_prep.as_of, tmp.Actual
ORDER BY tmp.Date, tmp.HE ASC;
```

Below are the full table structures with pertinent sample data.

```
CREATE SCHEMA weather
CREATE TABLE weather.forecast
    (
    foretime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  as_of timestamp without time zone NOT NULL, -- in UTC
  summary text,
  precipintensity numeric(8,4),
  precipprob numeric(2,2),
  temperature numeric(5,2),
  apptemp numeric(5,2),
  dewpoint numeric(5,2),
  humidity numeric(2,2),
  windspeed numeric(5,2),
  windbearing numeric(4,1),
  visibility numeric(5,2),
  cloudcover numeric(4,2),
  pressure numeric(6,2),
  ozone numeric(5,2),
  preciptype text,
  lat numeric(8,6) NOT NULL,
  lon numeric(9,6) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT forecast_pkey PRIMARY KEY (foretime, as_of, lat, lon)
  );

INSERT INTO weather.forecast
    (windspeed, foretime, as_of, lat, lon)
VALUES
  (11.19,   '2/1/2016 8:00', '1/30/2016 23:00', 34.556, 28.345),
  (10.98,   '2/1/2016 8:00',    '1/31/2016 5:00', 34.556, 28.345),
  (10.64,   '2/1/2016 8:00',    '1/31/2016 11:00', 34.556, 28.345),
  (10.95,   '2/1/2016 8:00',    '1/31/2016 17:00', 34.556, 28.345),
  (10.39,   '2/1/2016 8:00',    '1/31/2016 23:00', 34.556, 28.345),
  (9.22,    '2/1/2016 8:00',    '2/1/2016 5:00', 34.556, 28.345),
  (10,  '2/1/2016 9:00',    '1/30/2016 11:00', 34.556, 28.345),
  (9.88,    '2/1/2016 9:00',    '1/30/2016 17:00', 34.556, 28.345),
  (10.79,   '2/1/2016 9:00',    '1/30/2016 23:00', 34.556, 28.345),
  (10.8,    '2/1/2016 9:00',    '1/31/2016 5:00', 34.556, 28.345),
  (10.35,   '2/1/2016 9:00',    '1/31/2016 11:00', 34.556, 28.345),
  (10.07,   '2/1/2016 9:00',    '1/31/2016 17:00', 34.556, 28.345),
  (9.57,    '2/1/2016 9:00',    '1/31/2016 23:00', 34.556, 28.345),
  (7.93,    '2/1/2016 9:00',    '2/1/2016 5:00', 34.556, 28.345)
;

CREATE TABLE weather.meso
(
  timestmp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  station text NOT NULL,
  lat numeric NOT NULL,
  lon numeric NOT NULL,
  tmp numeric,
  hum numeric,
  windspd numeric,
  winddir integer,
  dew numeric,
  CONSTRAINT meso_pkey PRIMARY KEY (timestmp, station, lat, lon)
);
INSERT INTO weather.meso
    (station, timestmp, lat, lon, windspd)
VALUES
  ('KSBN',  '2/1/2016 8:02', 34.556, 28.345, 16.1),
  ('KSBN',  '2/1/2016 8:12', 34.556, 28.345, 12.6),
  ('KSBN',  '2/1/2016 8:54', 34.556, 28.345, 11.5),
  ('KSBN',  '2/1/2016 9:02', 34.556, 28.345, 18.1),
  ('KSBN',  '2/1/2016 9:17', 34.556, 28.345, 12.2),
  ('KSBN',  '2/1/2016 9:48', 34.556, 28.345, 11.5)
;
```

This is the format of my desired output:

```
station   date       he  actual forecast   as_of  
KSBN      2/1/2016   4   10.4   15.1       1/31/2016 6:00  
KSBN      2/1/2016   5   12.7   11.32      1/31/2016 6:00
```

Comment: providing both some source data - in a reusable format - and the expected result - is the fastest method to gettig a workable solution.

Comment: @Used_By_Already Sorry to ask a newb question, but what is the best way to provide some source data?

Comment: **the** best is DDL for each table and a set of inserts, or just as a simple text table (presented like your sql code) is fine, or as an attached text file or spreadsheet. 9I don't like spreadsheets so much as they produce clutter to cleanup.) Keep in mind we don't want to deal with massive tables - it is just a SAMPLE that is needed. Add to your question so everyone can find it. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Used_By_Already I made some changes. Lemme know if that is how you like to see a question. And if the question makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The DDL and sample data do help comprehension however all I can propose is a bit more detail on how to leverage row_number, by example, which is also available online here http://rextester.com/FIEUPI83002

```
select
  row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY date_trunc('day', (foretime - interval '5 hours')) :: DATE 
                    ORDER BY case when extract(HOUR FROM (foretime - interval '5 hours')) < 10 then 1 else 2 end, AS_OF desc) AS rn
, extract(HOUR FROM (foretime - interval '5 hours')) HR
, foretime
, as_of
from forecast
order by RN, as_of DESC
```

The result of this, from the sample data available is as follows:

```
+----+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    | rn | date_part |      foretime       |        as_of        |
+----+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |  1 |         4 | 01.02.2016 09:00:00 | 01.02.2016 05:00:00 |
|  2 |  2 |         3 | 01.02.2016 08:00:00 | 01.02.2016 05:00:00 |
|  3 |  3 |         4 | 01.02.2016 09:00:00 | 31.01.2016 23:00:00 |
|  4 |  4 |         3 | 01.02.2016 08:00:00 | 31.01.2016 23:00:00 |
|  5 |  5 |         4 | 01.02.2016 09:00:00 | 31.01.2016 17:00:00 |
|  6 |  6 |         3 | 01.02.2016 08:00:00 | 31.01.2016 17:00:00 |
|  7 |  7 |         4 | 01.02.2016 09:00:00 | 31.01.2016 11:00:00 |
|  8 |  8 |         3 | 01.02.2016 08:00:00 | 31.01.2016 11:00:00 |
|  9 |  9 |         3 | 01.02.2016 08:00:00 | 31.01.2016 05:00:00 |
| 10 | 10 |         4 | 01.02.2016 09:00:00 | 31.01.2016 05:00:00 |
| 11 | 11 |         3 | 01.02.2016 08:00:00 | 30.01.2016 23:00:00 |
| 12 | 12 |         4 | 01.02.2016 09:00:00 | 30.01.2016 23:00:00 |
| 13 | 13 |         4 | 01.02.2016 09:00:00 | 30.01.2016 17:00:00 |
| 14 | 14 |         4 | 01.02.2016 09:00:00 | 30.01.2016 11:00:00 |
+----+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

So if you were to use the filter **WHERE RN = 1** the "most recent" row for each day, prior to 10 should be listed. I believe something like this will be appropriate to your requirements. Note it is the use of both a case expression and other columns that are ordering the row_number sequence (inside the OVER() clause) adjust that combination of columns to suit your needs.

---

original comment below

In the absence of sample data I will just discuss an approach; I suggest using **ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by date_time_column DESC)** *e.g.*

```
select
*
from (
  select *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY timestmp DESC) AS RN
  from forecast_table
  -- where timestmp < 10 am (include required logic ere)
  )
WHERE RN = 1
```

The row with a value of 1 in the computed column RN will be the most recent row due to the DESCendng order. This can be combined with **PARTITION BY** also so it the row_numebr approach is useful for finding "most recent" rows or "oldest" rows or even maximum/minium rows per partiion or overall.

Comment: Hi. I actually need the time and hour columns in ascending order. The tricky part for me is also getting the proper logic for that deadline I talk about. I attempted to solve it with that interval code on line 11, subtracting the day and going back 16 hour intervals.

Comment: That isn't the pont of my comment... to locate "the most recent row" use the technique shown, what you ten do after that row is found is up to you. You really want a fully worked answer provide A: **sample data** and B: **expected result** (not more words or images)

Comment: sorry just realised the order by should be by extracted date, then rn unable to fix further right now

Comment: Yeah, it needs to be the latest forecast for each unique pair of Foredate and foreHE. Can you take a stab at it? I'm stuggling with what you've guided me towards since I need this for each ForeDate, foreHE pair.

Comment: for *"each unique pair of Foredate and foreHE"* include both those columns in the **PARTITION BY** portion of the OVER(....) clause :: if you never try it you will never understand it.